# Run ipython notebook server and close terminal

Tags: bash, server, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to run ipython notebook server and close terminal?

If I run ipython notebook server like `ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8888 --ip 0.0.0.0` or `ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8888 --ip 0.0.0.0 &` and then close terminal, server also stopped.

Is there any way to avoid it (to run ipython notebook server for "forever") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preface your `ipython` command with `nohup`.  Then when the login session terminates that child process will not see the logout or "hang-up" signal that gets sent to all child processes on logout.

See `man nohup` for details.